# Are timing attacks exploitable if each key is used only once?

Tags: timing-attack

Suppose that one performs (for example) AES-GCM encryption and decryption using an algorithm that is vulnerable to timing attacks, but each key is used only once. Is it still possible to perform a successful timing attack?

Comment: You ask about AES-GCM specifically but you use a theoretical "algorithm that is vulnerable to timing attacks". Can you clarify if you are more interested in AES-GCM or just timing attacks in general?

Comment: Every block uses the same key, so if you encrypt 1 message, with 1000 blocks, you can leak more than enough subkey material to recover the complete key

Comment: @RichieFrame in AES-GCM, to be specific, each block is encrypted with a slightly different key because of the counter. Thus, if more than one block of plaintext are the same, they produce different cipher text blocks. So, really, the key *isn't* being used for each block directly.

Comment: @d1str0 each block does in fact use the exact same key, the counter is the plaintext input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Let's a thought experiment and not limit this to AES-GCM.

A very trivial example:

$M = \{0, 1\}$ (a one bit message)

$K = \{0, 1\}$ (a one bit key)

$E(m, k) = m \oplus k$

Let's say with this implementation the computation takes 100x as long if $k = 1$. Running this function only one time will give you a pretty good idea what k is based on how long it takes.

Again, this is just a trivial example meant for a thought experiment as to why you wouldn't necessarily *need* the encryption process to go more than once.

Another case might be that the plaintext has a series of repeated texts. All of which will be computed against the same key. This can be (not always) similar to computing a single plain text several times.